# Expresion regular para validar letras con acentos y ñ

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular con la cual valido "Nombres compuestos", pero esta no me admite acentos como tildes o "ñ" , necesito corregirlo

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s*[a-zA-Z]*)*[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar

```
^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$
```

`\u00f1 y \u00d1` son el equivalente para "ñ" y "Ñ", respectivamente
en ejemplo lo explicado

```js
function cambiarNombre(nombre){
let regex = /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$/g;
return regex.exec(nombre)[0];

}
console.log(cambiarNombre("ñoñerías"));
```

**EDITADO:** Había olvidado las tildes, ahora si admite tildes y otros, como diéresis

Comment: Tambien admite tildes esta expresion  ?

Comment: los acentos son `\u00E0-\u00FC`

Comment: Excelente ! funciona perfecto , muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @FABIANAGUILAR recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te ha servido. un saludo