# Prevenir error “Unicode Error ”

Tags: python, django

Estoy usando Django y dentro de mi proyecto se registran personal con diferentes nombres mismos que puedes contener caracteres extraños como:

```
tildes
Ñ
etc...
```

la idea es prevenir la mayor cantidad posible de errores, he usado algo como esto:

```
unicode(text_extraño)
```

tambien he usado

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

al inicio de mi archivo py
pero hay algunos caracteres que si los previene pero no todos completamente me gustaria saber si existe alguna forma global de prevenir esto y no estar controlando uno a uno los caracteres.

Adicional he visto algo como esto:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode
smart_str(text_extraño)
```

el cual de momento esta funcionando bien nose si este controlara todos los caracteres extraños, gracias cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Diego, ¿Qué debe pasar cuando se ingresen palabras con caracteres "extraños"? Quizás en lugar de centrarte en esos caracteres, podrías crear una expresión regular que contenga los caracteres **permitidos**, y luego validas cada palabra contra tu expresión.

Comment: claro eso entiendo, pero el problema es que debe aceptar caracteres extraños como tildesm ñ...que son comunes en nombres, direcciones, correos etc..

Comment: Aquí (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81041/expresion-regular-para-validar-letras-con-acentos-y-%C3%B1), hacen una expresión regular contempla los caracteres "normales", y algunos especiales.

Comment: A través de la biblioteca unicodedata ´import unicodedata´ puedes crear una función tipo a esta ´def normalize_unicode(string):
 return unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", string).encode("ascii","ignore").decode("ascii")´
Que te quita todas las tildes y caracteres extraños. Puedes  mirar la documentación para cambiar valores y encontrar lo que necesitas exactamente. P.D. Esta función solo chuta con cadenas unicode, pero si le cambias la codificación aceptará lo que sea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada gracias por sus aportes, tambien a **RodrigoN** que me hizo caer en cuenta que no se debe enfocar en un especifico caracter sino en el problema global.

Dicho esto el error generado **UnicodeEncodeError** se produce cuando se pasa una cadena Unicode que contiene caracteres que no están en inglés (caracteres Unicode más allá de 128) a algo que espera una intervención ASCII. La codificación predeterminada para un bytestring de Python es ASCII, "que maneja exactamente 128 caracteres (en inglés)". Esta es la razón por la que tratar de convertir caracteres Unicode más allá de 128 produce el error.

La solución se da con la función smart_str de Django en el módulo django.utils.encoding , convierte una cadena Unicode en una cadena de byte utilizando una codificación predeterminada de UTF-8.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode
smart_str(variable)
```

Sin duda en las diferentes pruebas que he realizado ha salido con éxito donde se probó con:

- Tildes
- Tildes diacriticas
- Ñ
- Dieresis, entre otros

Espero le sirva a alguien mas y si tienen comentarios o sugerencias para mejorar mi respuesta gracias dado que esto espero sirva a futuro como referencia..!!

**Fuente:**
[Unicode in the real world](https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/10/unicode/)

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion mas facil sin tener que tocar el código es ir a la opción Archivo/guardar se va a abrir una ventana donde se coloca el nombre del archivo, en la parte de abajo haya una opcion guardar con una flecha hacia abajo, al darle clic elegir la opción guardar con codificación y elegir la opción UNICODE UTF8 (está a lo último casi), con eso ya no les va a dar error. Espero les sirva. Saludos.