# problemas para validar las palabras con tilde usando laravel

Tags: php, validación

Colegas estoy intentando validar con php una cadena de caracteres y lo hago de la siguiente manera: `'acuerdo' => 'required|regex:/^[-áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑa-zA-Z0-9$#.() ]*$/',` pero en la cadena de texto que estoy enviando hay una palabra con tilde `económica` y en la validación detecta la tilde como un error. Se que puedo usar `Alpha` pero eso no resuelve mi problema porque puedo introducir en esta cadena de texto símbolos como `$`

Que me recomiendan hacer para solucionar este problema

Comment: ¿Responde [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81041/expresion-regular-para-validar-letras-con-acentos-y-%C3%B1) tu pregunta?

Comment: revise lo que me envio y no me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar usar `[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ$@!#?]*$` lo probé y funciona correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probe inclusive mi expresión y funciona, no se si tendre que poner la variable con un utf8_encode. No tengo idea porque las tildes son las únicas que las procesa como error

Answer (score 1):

Colegas estuve revisando la expresión que había implementado y no tenía ningún problema, aquí les muestro una imagen de la prueba realizada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en fin que la expresión esta bien y el problema debía ser algo más. Estuve revisando y la solución que encontré fuecutilizando `utf8_encode`, al parecer lo que estaba recibiendo con `tilde` no era correcto, quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
'acuerdo' => 'required|'. utf8_encode('regex:/^[áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑa-zA-Z-0-9$#.() ]*$/') .'|verificar_oracion:'.$input['acuerdo'],
```

Espero que esto les pueda servir a quien lo necesite.