# Aceptar solo letras y acentos en un input

Tags: javascript, html, input

Quiero que en el input solo se puedan escribir letras, pero a la hora que quiero poner acentos como por ejemplo "á" no me deja, este es el código que hice:

```javascript
function sololetras(e) {

  key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  teclado = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();
  letras = " abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
  especiales = "8-37-38-46-164";
  teclasEspeciales = false;

  for (var i in especiales) {
    if (key == especiales[i]) {
      teclasEspeciales = true; break;
    }
  }
  if (letras.indexOf(teclado) == -1 && !teclasEspeciales) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes reemplazar la variable letras por una regex como mencionan en las respuestas `const letras= /^[a-záéíóúñ ]/i;`, la regex incluye espacios, las letras con acentos y de la *a* a la *z*. También pienso que deberías sustituir `especiales` por un array tradicional en lugar de tener un string separado por guiones, `const especiales= [8, 37, 38, 46, 164]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez la solución mas sencilla seria agergando las letras con acentos a el conjunto de letras que mencionas.

```
function sololetras(e){

 key=e.keyCode || e.which;
 teclado=String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();
 letras = " áéíóúabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
 especiales="8-37-38-46-164";
 teclasEspeciales=false;

 for (var i in especiales){
   if (key==especiales[i]){
     teclasEspeciales=true;break;
   }
 }
 if(letras.indexOf(teclado)==-1 && ! teclasEspeciales){
  return false;
 }     
}
```

ó podrias saber el codigo de la letra que quieres, agregando un **alert(key)** y agregarlas a las especiales

Comment: Me funciono soy nuevo. ¡Muchas gracias!.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de hacerlo es mediante el uso de expresiones regulares (que son un conjunto de caracteres que representan un patrón de búsqueda). Por ejemplo si desea verificar que una cadena solo contiene letras puede hacer lo siguiente:

```js
let expresionRegular = /[a-z]/
console.log(expresionRegular.test('hola'))
```

al ejecutar esas dos lineas de códigos, en la terminal aparece `true` indicando de que la cadena coincide con la expresión regular, pero para efectos de la pregunta en este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81041/expresion-regular-para-validar-letras-con-acentos-y-%C3%B1) hay una respuesta a lo que esta buscando.