# ¿Cómo agrego la Ñ y letras tildadas en mi Regular Expression en MVC ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Quería saber cómo puedo agregar la letra "Ñ", tanto en mayúscula y minúscula en el RegularExpression de mi Modelo de datos.

Actualmente lo tengo asi:

```
     [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Solo se permiten letras para el Nombre.")]
     public string Nombre { get; set; }
```

Esto funciona bien pero la Ñ no me la toma ni las letras tildadas (á, Á, é, É, etc...).

Comment: No funciona con [a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ] ?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81041/expresion-regular-para-validar-letras-con-acentos-y-%C3%B1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí añado las ñ, letras tildadas y las Ç

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙüÜçÇ'])$", ErrorMessage = "Solo se permiten letras para el Nombre.")]
     public string Nombre { get; set; }
```